# Where can I find a list of build lifecycle events for grails?

Tags: grails

Is there a list or some way to excavate for all the events that the core build system fires (i.e., things you can listen for in a _Events.groovy script?  The grails docs list a few "common" ones -- is there no list of "all" of them?

(I know you can create additional events, and that plugins often do -- so there's no such thing as a comprehensive list of these events -- I'm just asking about the ones that can be thrown by an out-of-the-box Grails installation for all the standard build operations.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Scott Davis actually [suggests](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/j-grails08128/index.html) a method for finding this out in his post on the Grails event model. However, his method will only find scripts in a single directory.

Assuming you're on a UNIX system, you can cd into your $GRAILS_HOME directory and run `grep "event(" */**.groovy` to find all the core scripts that fire an event.

Here's a sample output from my Grails 2.3.3 directory.

## Just the Event Strings

- StatusFinal
- CreatedFile
- StatusUpdate
- StatusError
- StatusUpdate
- IntegrateWithInit
- StatusError
- StatusError
- StatusUpdate
- StatusUpdate
- StatusError
- StatusFinal
- StatusFinal
- StatsStart
- StatusUpdate
- StatusUpdate
- StatusUpdate
- StatusFinal
- AppLoadEnd
- AppCfgEnd
- StatusError
- StatusError
- StatusError
- CreatedFile
- CreatedArtefact
- StatusFinal
- StatusFinal
- DocSkip
- DocStart
- StatusError
- DocEnd
- DocSkip
- DocStart
- StatusError
- DocEnd
- DocSkip
- DocStart
- DocEnd
- DocSkip
- DocStart
- DocEnd
- SetClasspath
- StatusFinal
- StatusFinal
- PackagingEnd
- PackagePluginStart
- PackagePluginEnd
- StatusUpdate
- StatusError

## Full grep Output

```
scripts/BugReport.groovy:    event("StatusFinal", ["Created bug-report ZIP at $zipName"])
scripts/CreateController.groovy:        event("CreatedFile", [viewsDir])
scripts/InstallAppTemplates_.groovy:    event('StatusUpdate', ["Application templates installed to $destination"])
scripts/InstallPlugin.groovy:            event("StatusError", [ ERROR_MESSAGE])
scripts/InstallTemplates.groovy:    event("StatusUpdate", ["Templates installed successfully"])
scripts/IntegrateWith.groovy:        event("IntegrateWithInit", keys.toList())
scripts/PluginInfo_.groovy:        event("StatusError", ["Usage: grails plugin-info <plugin-name> [version]"])
scripts/RunScript.groovy:        event('StatusError', ['ERROR: Required script name parameter is missing'])
scripts/RunScript.groovy:            event('StatusUpdate', ["Running script $scriptFile ..."])
scripts/RunScript.groovy:            event('StatusUpdate', ["Script $scriptFile complete!"])
scripts/RunScript.groovy:        event('StatusError', ["Designated script doesn't exist: $scriptFile"])
scripts/SetVersion.groovy:        event("StatusFinal", [ "Plugin version updated to $newVersion"])
scripts/SetVersion.groovy:        event("StatusFinal", [ "Application version updated to $newVersion"])
scripts/Stats.groovy:    event("StatsStart", [pathToInfo])
scripts/Upgrade.groovy:        event("StatusUpdate", ["NOTE: Your application currently expects grails version [$gv], " +
scripts/Upgrade.groovy:            event("StatusUpdate", ["Executing ${pluginDir.getFilename()} plugin upgrade script"])
scripts/Upgrade.groovy:    event("StatusUpdate", ["Please make sure you view the README for important information about changes to your source code."])
scripts/Upgrade.groovy:    event("StatusFinal", ["Project upgraded"])
scripts/_GrailsBootstrap.groovy:    event("AppLoadEnd", ["Loading Grails Application"])
scripts/_GrailsBootstrap.groovy:    event("AppCfgEnd", ["Configuring Grails Application"])
scripts/_GrailsCompile.groovy:            event("StatusError", ["Compilation error: ${e.cause.message}"])
scripts/_GrailsCompile.groovy:            event("StatusError", ["GSP Compilation error in file $e.cause.fileName at line $e.cause.lineNumber: $e.cause.message"])
scripts/_GrailsCompile.groovy:            event("StatusError", ["Compilation error: ${e.cause?.message ?: e.message}"])
scripts/_GrailsCreateArtifacts.groovy:    event("CreatedFile", [artifactFile])
scripts/_GrailsCreateArtifacts.groovy:    event("CreatedArtefact", [ artifactFile, className])
scripts/_GrailsCreateProject.groovy:    event("StatusFinal", ["Created Grails Application at ${new File(basedir).canonicalPath}"])
scripts/_GrailsCreateProject.groovy:    event("StatusFinal", [ "Created plugin ${pluginName}" ])
scripts/_GrailsDocs.groovy:        event("DocSkip", ['groovydoc'])
scripts/_GrailsDocs.groovy:    event("DocStart", ['groovydoc'])
scripts/_GrailsDocs.groovy:        event("StatusError", ["Error generating groovydoc: ${e.message}"])
scripts/_GrailsDocs.groovy:    event("DocEnd", ['groovydoc'])
scripts/_GrailsDocs.groovy:        event("DocSkip", ['javadoc'])
scripts/_GrailsDocs.groovy:    event("DocStart", ['javadoc'])
scripts/_GrailsDocs.groovy:            event("StatusError", ["Error generating javadoc: ${e.message}"])
scripts/_GrailsDocs.groovy:    event("DocEnd", ['javadoc'])
scripts/_GrailsDocs.groovy:        event("DocSkip", ["refdocs"])
scripts/_GrailsDocs.groovy:        event("DocStart", ["refdocs"])
scripts/_GrailsDocs.groovy:        event("DocEnd", ["refdocs"])
scripts/_GrailsDocs.groovy:        event("DocSkip", ['pdf'])
scripts/_GrailsDocs.groovy:    event("DocStart", ['pdf'])
scripts/_GrailsDocs.groovy:    event("DocEnd", ['pdf'])
scripts/_GrailsEvents.groovy:event('SetClasspath', [classLoader])
scripts/_GrailsInit.groovy:            event("StatusFinal", ["Application expects grails version [$appGrailsVersion], but GRAILS_HOME is version " +
scripts/_GrailsInit.groovy:        event("StatusFinal", ["Application metadata not found, please run: grails upgrade"])
scripts/_GrailsPackage.groovy:    event("PackagingEnd",[])
scripts/_GrailsPluginDev.groovy:    event("PackagePluginStart", [pluginInfo.name])
scripts/_GrailsPluginDev.groovy:    event("PackagePluginEnd", [pluginInfo.name])
scripts/_GrailsWrapper.groovy:    event("StatusUpdate", [ "Wrapper installed successfully"])
scripts/_PluginDependencies.groovy:    pluginInstallEngine.eventHandler = { eventName, msg -> event(eventName, [msg]) }
scripts/_PluginDependencies.groovy:        event("StatusError", [msg])
```

Comment: Also, it looks like Hayden has done similar work and posted the results at http://mentaldetritus.blogspot.com/2011/09/grails-events.html, though that's from back in 2011.

Comment: Good enough.  Thanks @jonnybot

Comment: I think there must be events that can't be found this way -- ones that are fired from Grails build system objects (not scripts). Anyone have a comprehensive list of those?